# Calculating Square Root recursively in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, square-root

The following code works but I don't quite understand how the arguments are mapped to the parameter lists. Please be aware Im new to Scala.

```
import Math.abs

val tolerance = 0.0001
def isCloseEnough(x: Double, y: Double) =
  abs((x - y) / x) / x < tolerance

def fixedPoint(f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double) = {
  def iterate(guess: Double): Double = {
    val next = f(guess)
    if (isCloseEnough(guess, next)) next
    else iterate(next)
  }
  iterate(firstGuess)
}

def averageDamp(f: Double => Double)(x: Double) = (x + f(x)) / 2

def sqrt(x: Double) =
  fixedPoint(averageDamp(y => x / y))(1.0)

sqrt(2.0)
```

The body of the `sqrt` function above is `fixedPoint(averageDamp(y => x / y))(1.0)`

where

`(y => x / y)` maps to `(f: Double => Double)` of the `averageDamp` function and

`(1.0)` maps to `(firstGuess: Double)` of the `fixedPoint` function but

looks like nothing maps to `(x: Double)` of the `averageDamp` function.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [currying](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/currying.html). What's really happening is that `averageDamp(y => x / y)` is being interpreted as a function: `Double => Double`, because once you set the first parameter list to a particular set of values, you obtain a function that takes the second parameter list.

For example, consider the following code:

```
def multiply(x: Double)(y: Double) = x * y

val multiplyByFive: Double => Double = multiply(5)
println(multiplyByFive(2)) // 10
println(multiplyByFive(6)) // 30
```

As you see, the fact of applying `multiply` with only one parameter list out of two creates a new function of the second parameter list (here `(y: Double)`) that has a fixed set of values for the first parameter list (here `(5)`).

Another equivalent way to write this, which perhaps will be more explicit for you, is the following :

```
val multiplyByFive: Double => Double = multiply(5)(_)
```

Here we explicitly apply the function with two parameters lists, but using a wildcard for the second, which is a way to tell to the compiler to create a function that replaces the underscore by a parameter of the function.

Comment: Thank you, now I comprehend.